# Why doesn't my WebMail.Send work outside of the web root folder?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, roles, webmail

I have a Contact.cshtml page in the root folder with a form that the user fills out to send an email.  It works fine.

When I move it to an Admin folder (protected with roles, ie. Roles.IsUserInRole), I get a connection/timeout error.

My WebMail is configured in my _AppStart.cshtml page which resides in the root.

There is a web.config for the Admin folder but it only has an authorization statement and a couple of connection strings (unrelated).

I just can't figure out why the WebMail works in the root and not the Admin folder.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out after a day or so.  The issue appears to be different folder permissions in the sub-folder than the root.  Once I duplicated the permissions to the sub-folder the WebMail worked as expected.